# How to make comma elements in Excel sheet be in their own row, with identical data for other columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

What I  mean is,

turn this:

```
| ID || Names |
| 1  ||A, B, C|
| 2  ||A, D, F|
```

into this:

```
| ID || Name |
| 1  ||A|
| 1  ||B|
| 1  ||C|
| 2  ||A|
| 2  ||D|
| 2  ||F|
```

The data I'm trying to transform has 1048576 rows and 2 columns (like in the example), and I don't need it to be reversible. I tried making a C program that can transform the data by deleting all `"` characters and replace them with `ID,`  but that didn't work out as expected.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it, otherwise this question is likely to be closed due to lack of preliminary work from your side.

Comment: @DarkDiamond This is a question website, no? What's the point of posting questions alongside their answers? 
I'm unexperienced in Excel and have been trying to solve this for a few days so I thought I should ask for help, guess I was wrong?

Comment: I don't know if this is trivial to solve and Excel has a built in feature to solve this, so I'm asking for help on a topic I don't know about.

Comment: Power Query may be good for this.

Comment: It is not possible in Excel. Your original data, with 1048576 rows, cannot be expanded to more rows. You are already at the hard limit for the number of rows in a worksheet.

Comment: We don't expect you to have the answer. We expect you to have TRIED SOMETHING, and then shown us what you've tried so we know a) you've put some effort into this and b) we won't duplicate something you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Power Query in Excel:
Select the **Range**- go to **Data**- **From Table/Range**- Open the **Power Query editor**:

[image]

Open **Power Query Editor**- select **Names** column- go to **Home**- **Split Column**- **By Delimiter**:

[image]

Select **Custom**- enter **,** - click **OK**:

[image]

Select **Names.1, Names.2 and Names.3**- go to **Transform**- Select **Unpivot Columns**- **Remove Attribute** column and change the **Value** column name to **Name** column- go to **Home**- **Close & Load**:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]